# Customize column for django-tables as drop down list

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have a table in which I compare the two versions of a selected Data.
This data actually has more than one version stored, so in my table I have column as:

```
    class ver_compare(tables.Table):
       new_db = tables.CheckBoxColumn()
       data = tables.Column()
       current_rev = tables.Column()
       next_rev = tables.Column()*
```

Now the last field I want as a each cell to have a drop down list of version to select from, something similar to choicefield.
Is there any approach to go along??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can you write some html by hand? in django template, loop the "versions" and generate html yorself could easily achieve waht you want. do you know how to manipulate dom using jQuery and other js tools?

Comment: Actually I'm not that aware about using Jquery and other js tools

Comment: that's a pity, @Karan you should take some time and learn it. python/django is not the best way to solve this problem, html + js is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use TemplateColumn. Here you have the simplest mockup I can think of . Of course you need to change template to something more useful.

```
countries = [
    {'name': 'Australia', 'population': 21, 'tz': 'UTC +10', 'visits': 1},
    {'name': 'Germany', 'population': 81, 'tz': 'UTC +1', 'visits': 2},
    {'name': 'Mexico', 'population': 107, 'tz': 'UTC -6', 'visits': 0},
]

template = """
<select>
<option{% if record.visits = 0%} selected {% endif %}>0
<option{% if record.visits = 1%} selected {% endif %}>1
<option{% if record.visits = 2%} selected {% endif %}>2
</select>
"""

class CountryTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column()
    population = tables.Column()
    tz = tables.Column(verbose_name='time zone')
    visits = tables.TemplateColumn(template)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly fine...need to change the template and incorporate the version's dictionary

Comment: I was looking into rendering the template after class but it isn't showing into the web page

Comment: What do you mean by rendering a class? Only templates can be rendered.

Comment: I meant rendering the template after table class because that way i will have this dropdown list based on particular record in the row i defined a method `def render_new_revision(self, record, value):`