# django-tables2: create a input text box

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-tables2

I would like to create a table with multiple columns that display existing data, and one column that contains a text box where I can input data.

When I use my "Animal" model in my forms.py, I see entry boxes. However, when I use the same model in my tables.py, I see a '--' (dashes) instead of the entry boxes.

My models.py:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    specie = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    count = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

my forms.py:

```
class AnimalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
```

my tables.py:

```
class AnimalTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
```

I even tried to manually specify a textbox, but that didn't help:

```
class AnimalTable(tables.Table):
    count = forms.Textarea()
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
```

How would one create a entry box inside a django-tables2 table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a usable solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326234/customize-column-for-django-tables-as-drop-down-list).

```
TEMPLATE = """
<input id="count" maxlength="100" name="count" type="text"/>
"""
class AnimalTable(tables.Table):
    count = tables.TemplateColumn(TEMPLATE)
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
```

I hope this will prove helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have misunderstood the concept of the `django-tables2` package. Its purpose is to display tabular data with the ability to sort them and some other formatting stuff. So you just cant add formfields into `tables.Table` class, because it expects columns.

The list of supported columns is available in the documentation here: http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#built-in-columns